# year value in table in oracle

Tags: oracle, date-format

I have this query in oracle:

```
 DELETE FROM my_table
 WHERE to_date(last_update, 'DD/MM/YYYY') < to_date('01/01/2000', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

when I run this, I get this error:
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999 and must not be 0

there is not any 0 value in the table.

any one knows what is the problem?

Comment: What is the data type of your last_update column?

Comment: @Kapitany it is:
DATE                          DEFAULT to_date('1900 01 01', 'yyyy mm dd') NOT NULL

Comment: Do not use `TO_DATE` on values that are already a `DATE` data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you have stored your dates as a string with the `DD/MM/YYYY` format; it would be better if you stored them all as a `DATE` data type and then you would not have to do this conversion (and you would be using the most appropriate data type for the data).

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  TO_DATE( last_update, 'DD/MM/YYYY' DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR ) IS NULL;
```

To identify the rows that are raising that exception.

---

If you are already storing them as a `DATE` data type then don't use `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a `DATE` as `TO_DATE` expects a string so Oracle will implicitly cast your `DATE` to a string and then try to convert it back and your query is effectively:

```sql
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE  TO_DATE(
         TO_CHAR(
           last_update,
           ( SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_SETTINGS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
         ),
         'DD/MM/YYYY'
       ) < to_date('01/01/2000', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

And if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and your format model do not match then you will get errors (or, worse, the query will succeed and your data will be inconsistent as it may have swapped days and months or months and years).

Instead, just use:

```sql
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE last_update < DATE '2000-01-01';
```

Answer (score 1):

If the datatype of last_update is date, don't use the to_date function:

```
DELETE FROM my_table
 WHERE last_update < to_date('01/01/2000', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```